# postfix error with big attachments - postfix/smtpd[pid]: lost connection after DATA (6 bytes)

Tags: php, attachment, postfix-mta

I am using PHP to send mail via postfix (PHP and postfix running on the same server), everything is working fine when the attachements are small (less than 10mb), but as soon as I increase the attachment size to 20mb I get the following error in the log:

postfix/smtpd[454]: lost connection after DATA (6 bytes) from ...

Here are some of the postfix config values:

```
postconf | grep "size"
berkeley_db_create_buffer_size = 16777216
berkeley_db_read_buffer_size = 131072
body_checks_size_limit = 51200
bounce_size_limit = 50000
header_size_limit = 102400
mailbox_size_limit = 51200000
message_size_limit = 104857600
tcp_windowsize = 0
```

I have tried the following but it didnt work:

```
ifconfig eth0 mtu 1492
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Dixit the postfix FAQ at http://www.postfix.org/faq.html, it could be linked to a firewall :

> Every now and then, mail fails with "timed out while sending end of data -- message may be sent more than once", or with: "lost connection after DATA". Network outages happen, systems crash. There isn't much you can do about it. Usually the problem goes away by itself.
>   However, when you see mail deliveries fail consistently, you may have a different problem: broken path MTU discovery. Or it could be a broken PIX firewall.